# Слайдер с анимацией отступа между элементами

Tags: javascript, css, анимация, slider

возникла проблема с анимированием слайдера. На скриншотах принципе весь процесс виден. При скролле слайдера, должен появляться отступ между элементами, как гармошка, Используется библиотека (на данный момент) Swiper Slider. Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать, как реализовать подобную анимацию ? Есть ли такая возможность ?

Через width и margin'ы пробовал, контент начинается дергаться.

Может быть кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей ?

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]